# Command to return just the value of the current server load?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I know you can get server load for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes using commands like "w".  However, I would like to automatically retrieve one of those values via a cron job so I can make a note of it in a database and do some analysis and watch the trends.  So... I need a command that will output JUST the server load so it can be simply treated as a number for use in my script.  Can anyone give me a command that will parse output from a command like "w" and return only the server load value?  I'd love to have variations that will return the 5 and 15 minute averages as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Each of them, 1, 5 and 15 minute load averages:

```
cut -f1 -d' ' /proc/loadavg
cut -f2 -d' ' /proc/loadavg
cut -f3 -d' ' /proc/loadavg
```

Comment: +1 cut is so handy for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
CpuLoadAverage=`uptime | awk 'BEGIN { FS=" |, " } { print $11 }'`
echo $CpuLoadAverage
```

for 5 and 15 minutes, just replace $11 with $12 or $13.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uptime | perl -e 'while (<>) { m/average:\s(\d.\d+),\s(\d.\d+),\s(\d.\d+)/; print $1; }'
```

for the 1-minute average, or replace `$1` with `$2` or `$3` for the 5-minute or 15-minute averages respectively.

Comment: Perl's a little heavy for that, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah... I wanted to do it with awk or cut but I couldn't remember the syntax.